# Avoid remanent zeros in BYROW SUM formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to use BYROW to SUM the values of many columns. I need the sum only if the first column "Type" has values (something like if A2:A <> ""), but I don't know the optimum way to do it with this kind of range in a BYROW formula.

Here is my example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mfja-LzHtW3rBPMSWGlX5geRGZkfQU_L9uk6tWOKG88/edit?usp=sharing
Formula is in green cell.

It could be more types in A column, so I want to keep the A2:F range in the formula.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455), which make the question useless for others or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=BYROW(A2:F;LAMBDA(base;if(counta(base)=0;;SUM(base))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try-

```
=BYROW(A2:INDEX(F2:F;COUNTA(F2:F));LAMBDA(base;SUM(base)))
```

[image]